# Is it possible to include Xaml resources in a ControlTemplate?

Tags: silverlight, xaml, resources, controltemplate

I'm working on a Silverlight templated control (i.e. it derives from Control and has its look implemented as a ControlTemplate in generic.xaml) and came across the need for a ValueConverter in one of my bindings.  Normally I'd just create an instance of the ValueConverter in the Resources of the control working with but I can't figure out how to do that with a ControlTemplate.  I'd like to keep this implementation all in Xaml if possible, but I suppose I could override OnApplyTemplate and manually create the binding with a converter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This does work in Silverlight 3.  You just need to add a resources section inside your Control Template, and add the ValueConverter to the template's resources:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="controls:MyControl">
    <Grid Margin="8,40,8,20" x:Name="peopleListContainer">        
        <Grid.Resources>
            <controls:MyValueConverter x:Key="converter" />
        </Grid.Resources>
        <!-- ....
```

However, ValueConverters are often misused in Control Templates.  You may want to use a TypeConverter instead.  Bryant Likes wrote a good article discussing [the difference between ValueConverter and TypeConverter in this scenario](http://blogs.sqlxml.org/bryantlikes/archive/2008/11/24/silverlight-ivalueconverter-vs-typeconverter.aspx).